# Ubuntu ODBC without FreeTDS

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu, odbc

I am wondering if it is possible to use only ODBC driver from Microsoft site, without FreeTDS, to acces MS SQL DB from PHP?

1. I was following this page originally on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and completed the installation of ODBC driver v17 for Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04 and 17.10:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server

2. After that i tried to connect from PHP using "odbc_connect()" but it resulted with:
   ***Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'odbc_connect' not found in /var/www/html/oop/process.php:20 Stack trace: #0 ...***
3. After a failed attempt I wend reading some more and saw some people insist on having Driver Manager (even though documentation says *"The driver manager dependency is resolved automatically by the package management system when you install the Microsoft ODBC Driver 13, 13.1, or 17 for SQL Server on Linux"*), and others say I am missing FreeTDS ...

So now I am very confused about what I did wrong and how to continue, but at the same time I would generally want to avoid FreeTDS, because it seems to be built on an older definition of TDS standard by Microsoft and limiting in some cases (I already used it before), but would rather like to migrate to "Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux".

I have one page with a form, and another one to "POST" to ... but in that second one called "process.php" I couldn't even get past establishing connection with DB part, let alone CRUD.

**First file "form.php":**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>PHP OOP Reg Form</title>
    <style>
      body{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background: black
      }

      #form{
        width: 30%;
        height: 400px;
        background: white;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid red;
      }

      input{
        width: 200px;
        height: 30px;
        margin: 5px;
        display: block;
      }

      label{
        margin: 5px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="form">
      <h2>Registration form:</h2>
      <form method="POST" action="process.php">
        <label>User name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your username" required="required"/>

        <label>E-mail:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your e-mail" required="required"/>

        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Enter your password" required="required"/>

        <input type="SUBMIT" name="signup" value="Sign up"/>
      </form>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>

<?php

  include "process.php";

  $db = new db();

?>
```

**Second file "process.php":**

```html
<?php

  class db{
    public $host = "IP ADDRESS\INSTANCE";
    public $user = "sa";
    public $pass = "sa_pass";
    public $db_name = "some_db";

    public $link;

    public function __construct(){
      $this->connect();
    }

    private function connect(){

      $this->link = new odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=$this->host;Database=$this->db_name;", $this->user, $this->pass);

    }
  }



?>
```

Comment: IMHO, this should be asked on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), it has little to do with PHP. Also you shouldn't ask us for an opinion, but show what you did and try to find an answer to your problem

Comment: @Cemal - true, I apologize for missing out on the source code ... I've added the code to the question above, as suggested. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well you don't need odbc to access ms sql database from php. You can also use pdo

Comment: @Cemal - could please you point me in the right direction by referencing some good reading materials on the subject? I will for sure consider PDO as a viable substitute and go trough the documentation on  http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php . Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: here is an [MS article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/example-application-pdo-sqlsrv-driver) and [a google search](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1ASUM_enTR524TR524&ei=S4mOWobxBoOMgAapj5CABA&q=php+pdo+mssql+tutorial&oq=php+pdo+mssql+tuto&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i22i30k1l2.174063.175185.0.176443.5.5.0.0.0.0.167.642.0j4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.4.639...0j0i22i10i30k1.0.B_kXxEKfzI4) for you

Comment: But, is PDO depending on FreeTDS as stated in the manual? ("_PDO_DBLIB is a driver that implements the PHP Data Objects (PDO) interface to enable access from PHP to Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase databases through the **FreeTDS library**._").

Comment: no, PDO is a generic library for php that depends on driver files, and `PDO_DBLIB` is one of those driver files, that uses `FreeTDS`. You define which driver to use on connection dsn in PDO. PDO provides a set of functions that is same(mostly) regardless of the underlying dbms driver files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by utilizing either of these scripts (shout-out to Cemal for pointing me in the right direction):

**Script 1:**

```html
// Specify the server and connection string attributes
$serverName = "SERV_IP_ADR\INSTANCE, PORT_NO";

// Get UID and PWD from application-specific files.
$uid = "sa";
$pwd = "sa_pass";
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,
                         "PWD"=>$pwd,
                         "Database"=>"DB_name");

// Connect using SQL Server Authentication.
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false )
{
     echo "Unable to connect.</br>";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

or

**Script 2:**

```html
$serverName = "SERVER_IP_ADDRESS\INSTANCE, PORT";

/* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */
try
{
$conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database=DB_name", "sa", "sa_pass");
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) );
}
```